# function() vs function issue in javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, html

I created an **Image Element** on we page **dynamically** via javaScript.
And I want to set onClick for my new created image element .

I face with an issue and I don't know why ?,

My Original Code :

```html
<html>
<body>

<button type="button" onclick="createImgNote()">Get line height</button>

<script>

function createImgNote() { 
 var img = document.createElement('img'); 
 img.src ='ic_notebook.png'; 
 img.style.left="100px";
 img.style.top="150px";
 img.style.position = "absolute";
 img.onclick = imgClick;
 document.body.appendChild(img); 
 }

function imgClick()
{
 alert("imgClick called");
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use `img.onclick = createImgNote` means my function **without** () 
**Browser** make image first and then **each time user clicks on image**, Broswer executes my onclick function.

But When I use `img.onclick = createImgNote()` means my onclick function with () 
**Browser** excutes my function first and then create image element and finally created image element is not clickable.

If any one knows this issue please  tell me why this issue happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you do `img.onclick = createImgNote` it assigns that function to that event listener.

When you do `img.onclick = createImgNote()` it calls the function and assigns the return value to that listener. anytime you follow a function with () you are calling the function.