# Onclick calling functions diffrences

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can I am on working on a react project and I was wondering what is a difference between different onClick function calling ,meaning:

```
<Button onClick={function}> 
<Button onClick={function()}>

<Button onClick={()=>function()}>
<Button onClick={()=>function}>
```

I have seen multiple methods but I still can't get a grap on the core of their differences,thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [function() vs function issue in javascript onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152178/function-vs-function-issue-in-javascript-onclick)

Comment: (The above isn't react specific, but neither is your question. This is just a matter of whether you're assigning a function or the return value of a function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original post, there's already a post on function() vs function.

In summary (and in layman terms), though, there are 2 ways on how you handle onClick.

**When you want to pass some value to the function**

```
//the button
<button onClick={() => myFunction('I am a click')}>Button</button>


//the function
const myFunction = (value) => {
     console.log(value) //prints 'I am a click'
}
```

**When you do NOT need to pass any value (events/default props will be passed by default)**

```
//the button
<button onClick={myEvent}>Button</button>


//the function
const myFunction = (event) => {
     console.log(event) //prints the button element
}
```

##### Creating a custom Button component with custom props.

```
const MyButton = ({ onClick }) => {
   const customOnClick = () => {
       onClick('Somebody', 'Special'); //we call the onclick here
   }   

   return <button onClick={customOnClick}>Click Me</button>
}

const App =() => {

   //the onClick in MyButton component actually triggers this function.
   const onClick = (value, value2) => {
       console.log(value,value2) //prints "Somebody Special"
   }
   return (<MyButton onClick={onClick} />) // i do not need to specify the props to pass
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button onClick={function}>
```

Assigns the *reference* of a declared function to the click listener. This is preferable.

```
<Button onClick={function()}>
```

Assigns the result of *calling* the function to the click listener. You probably don't want to do this unless the function returns a function of its own, [also known as a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
<Button onClick={() => function()}>
```

This is basically the same as the first example but [in React this function expression is defined each time the component is rendered](https://www.velotio.com/engineering-blog/inline-function-performance-in-react-applications) so you may have some performance issues if your app scales. The first example is preferable.

```
<Button onClick={() => function}>
```

Doesn't do anything useful. Avoid.